# hook_menu not working on a custom module

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-hooks, webpage-rendering, hook-menu

May be I am something obvious but a simple custom Hello world module isn't working. I have spent a couple of days trying to fix this but no progress at all.

hello_world.info

```
name = Hello World
description = "This module is to test hello world"
core = 7.x
```

hello_world.module

```
<?php
/**
* Implements hook_init()
*/

function oulta_hello_world_init() {
  drupal_set_message("From Hello World Module");
}

/**
* Implements hook_menu()
*/

function hello_world_menu() {
  $items['hello_world'] = array(
  'title' => 'Just saying hello world',
  'page callback' => 'hello_world_pg',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function hello_world_pg() {
  drupal_set_message("Hello World page called");
  return 'Hello world!';
}
```

I am trying to access the page at localhost/mysite/hello_world/

The path for .module and .info files is htdocs/mysite/sites/all/modules/custom

Since hook_menu is fundamental to development, I am stuck. Please help.

BTW are there are alternatives for hook_menu for rendering pages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to be

```
function hello_world_menu() {
  $items = array(); // define the $items array

  $items['hello_world'] = array(
  'title' => 'Just saying hello world',
  'page callback' => 'hello_world_pg',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

And then flush your website cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Muhammad but this didn't change the behavior.

Comment: What's inside the function `hello_world_pg()`? And what happens when you go to the page `/hello_world`

Comment: And do you see any output message for `drupal_set_message("From Hello World Module");` inside your `hook_menu()` implementation ?

Comment: No. All I see is the message as a result of the _init() function. Here's something interesting.

Comment: this is the message in the logs. PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'MENU_NORMAL_ITEM' for column 'type' at row 5: INSERT INTO {menu_router} (path, load_functions, to_arg_functions, access_callback, access_arguments, page_callback, page_arguments, delivery_callback, fit, number_parts, context, tab_parent, tab_root, title, title_callback, title_arguments, theme_callback, theme_arguments, type, description, position, weight, include_file) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1...

Answer (score 0):

After trying out myriad solutions, it still didn't work. I came to a conclusion that this was a result of database corruption. Loaded an older database and Voila everything started working.